# PHP / Curl Incoming Webhook to MS Teams doesn't work all of the time

Tags: php, curl, microsoft-teams

I am using an incoming webhook on a web app to post some data to teams. I got this working in CURL after looking up some implementation methods, but it should be noted I have no experience in CURL. The thing is, it works about half the time, then the other half this comes up in the error log:

```
[01-Feb-2021 09:00:59 Europe/London] Error: Could not resolve host: outlook.office.com
```

Was hoping someone can take a look and see if there is something obvious I am doing wrong. This is the code used in my PHP file (with the webhook ID removed for privacy)

```
// Generated by curl-to-PHP: http://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/

$ch = curl_init();           
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'webhook-id-here');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "{\"text\": \"$teamsMessage\"}");

$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    error_log("Error: " . curl_error($ch), 0);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a DNS problem. **Could not resolve host: outlook.office.com**.

Maybe any firewall involved in blocking that? Remove `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE`.

Try this simplified solution, which works well for me. I am using JSON header instead of form encoding.

```
// Paste the URL here
$url = 'https://outlook.office.com/webhook/XXX';

// Use the text encoded as MARKDOWN.
// Any markdown character needs to be escaped!
$body = ['text' => 'Hello World'];

$curlHandle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt_array($curlHandle, [
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER     => ['Content-Type: application/json'],
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => json_encode($body)
]);

$response = curl_exec($curlHandle);
curl_close($curlHandle);
if ($response !== '1') throw new Exception('No Response from MS incoming webhook API');
```

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to get back to me, and so quickly as well! I have tested this and can confirm it works but only time will tell if the same issue is happening for us. Annoyingly with the previous implementation, I couldn't immediately see if anything had worked because of the fact half the time it did actually work ha!

Comment: What also can be a reason is, that the Webhook URL do expire after one year.

Comment: The webhook probably would be older than that, but having said that I could replicate this issue we were having with another webhook created on a test channel in teams. Hopefully this JSON method fixes our issue, thanks again for your help.

Comment: If you had any text in the message which would break the JSON format, it would break, too. That won't happen with json_encode.

Comment: Hi Callum, Markus Zeller has provided accurate solution for this question.

Comment: I was waiting until the next time it got called to test for sure. The same error is still happening with the above code as well. Going to create a new webhook and see if it continues to happen.

Comment: @Saonti-MSFT No it isn't, so it seems it was down to the age of the webhook. I must admit this is incredibly frustrating as there was no warning it was close to expiring or had expired. It also didn't even stop working completely just about half the time.

Comment: In my case, Teams added an extra note in every message the webhook created. So the hint was clear to me.